# Is G2RL-1A-E a suitable replacement for G2RL-1A-E-HA relay in dishwasher

Tags: relay, replacement, ratings

I'm trying to figure out if the G2RL-1A-E power relay is a suitable replacement for a G2RL-1A-E-HA relay. When I study the [datasheet](https://asset.conrad.com/media10/add/160267/c1/-/en/002593560DS00/datenblatt-2593560-omron-g2rl-1a-e-ha-dc12-powerrelais-12-vdc-16-a-1-schliesser-1-st-bag.pdf), the only difference I see is that the market code distinguishes between "General purpose" and "Home Appliance according to IEC/EN60335-1". It is not clear to me what the practical difference is and whether the addition "HA" is a positive feature or not. Of course, I would prefer to simply use the identical component, but availability is very poor.

Background:
The heating in my dishwasher malfunctions. At the end of the cycle, the interior is completely cold and an error (E02) is reported. According to research on the Internet, this is a common problem caused by a faulty heating relay. See [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHp96IlqLtk) or [Forum](https://www.gasgewalt.de/tipps-und-tricks-links/tipps-im-alltag-nicht-f%C3%BCr-autos/geschirrsp%C3%BCler-fehler-e-02-beheben/) for similar issues, but different models. My model is one with the so called "Zeolith" heating, doing the fan trick does clear the error but after another cycle it appears again. Next option would be to replace one or more of the relays. Replacing the whole module would cost more than $300 instead of a couple of $ for the relays (and some work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the HA version and non HA version is in the way the relays respond to abnormal conditions. Over-voltage, over-current and over-heating are all the kinds of conditions that the relays must perform predictably under. One of the common stipulations under IEC/EN60335-1 is that devices must be effective at disconnecting current under the kinds of adverse conditions. This is absolutely critical in home appliances where the relays can cause fires or allow the appliance to electrocute someone under abnormal, but common, circumstances.

If everything is working as designed, and there are no abnormal events on your AC mains, then there is no difference between the relays, but if your dishwasher springs a small leak somewhere and water gets where it doesn't belong, using the HA version could be the only thing preventing you from getting electrocuted.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer!